# How to track if a variable value is used multiple times in same php while loop

Tags: php

I found this snippet in a different question and answer, and it detects if a variable value is the same as the variable value in the previous loop.

```
$prevValue = NULL;
while(condition) {
 if ($curValue == $prevValue) {
  //do stuff
 }
 $prevValue = $curValue;
}
```

However what I want to do is to check if a variable value has been used before in the loop, but anywhere in the loop, so if the value happened 1 or 2 or 10 loops ago I want it to tell me if the variable value has come through the loop before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array to store each value and then check if the current value is in the array:

```
$prevValues = array();
while(/*condition*/) {
    if (in_array($curValue, $prevValues)) {
        //do stuff
    }
    $prevValues[] = $curValue;
}
```

As [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) points out in a comment, you can do it this way as well.  It might be marginally faster but I haven't tested it:

```
while(/*condition*/) {
    if (isset($prevValues[$curValue])) {
        //do stuff
    }
    $prevValues[$curValue] = 1;  //set to whatever
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between [] and array() ?

Comment: @leoarce they both are array declaration. But `[]` works since 5.4 version of PHP (if I remember correctly)

Answer (score 6):

Make an array of previouse values and test by in_array function

```
$prevValue = [];
while(condition) {
 if (in_array($curValue, $prevValue)) {
  //do stuff
 }
 $prevValue[] = $curValue;
}
```

Comment: quicker check is to use the value as akey. `$prev[$val]`, then it's a simple isset() test, v.s. having to scan the array

Comment: @MarcB You are quite right. It's beautiful property of php arrays :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print out unique values, use `array_unique`.
Here is an example:

```
//This should output 2 3 1 4
$arr = array(2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4);
foreach(array_unique($arr) as $value){
    echo $value;
}
```